# Approaches to scaling E2E testing with SMS MFA (Twilio)

Tags: twilio, amazon-cognito, e2e-testing

Currently, I am using AWS Cognito for user management + MFA. For my E2E tests (run in-band), I have a user (test@email.com) in Cognito with a Twilio phone number. For every E2E test, the test user needs to sign in using the standard MFA flow:

- User inputs email + password
- Cognito verifies + sends MFA to associated phone number
- User enters MFA code in application
- Cognito verifies it and logs in

This is fine for a single E2E test suite being ran since there will be no race conditions with other E2E tests. Though if I were to scale this approach (multiple test suites ran in parallel), different test suites would be receiving login pins that will not be validated since Cognito invalidates previously sent MFA codes.

Having `N` unique phone numbers where the test suite will pick one at random will also not work because if I have `N+1` test suites running simultaneously, then the race condition will still exist.

Is there a more sound approach to scaling E2E tests using MFA?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to this question but let’s give it a try anyways for posterity.

I would personally “batch” your E2E tests.

For instance, let’s say you’d like to run 120 E2E tests in parallel. For this case I’d run 12 batches of 10 parallel tests with 10 different users with each a phone number attached.

In the case you need to have a unique user for each E2E test (which I presume you don’t at the moment), I would rotate phone numbers at the end of each test batch (through an admin-update-user-attributes call).

On our case we have gone with a more specialized solution like GetMyMFA which allows us to provision and deprovision phone numbers quickly and easily for MFA testing. Not sure if this kind of service would be more helpful for you.

Let me know what you think :)